# Copy rows with certain value vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hi all I have a sheet with more then 60 000 rows and I want to copy all rows to a new sheet if column of row contains certain value for example Energizer like in the following code

```
 Sub Macro3()
    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Set col = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)

    Set rngA = Range("A2", col)
    For Each cell In rngA
        If cell.Value = "Energizer" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Copy

        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Code doesn't work at all what could be done?

Comment: Your destination argument is non-existent.  Look at Help for the range.copy method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following copies all rows containing "Energizer" in column A into the clipboard.

```
    Sub Macro3()
    Dim rngA As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim col As Range
    Dim copiedRange As Range
    Dim r As Integer

    Set col = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    r = 0
    Set rngA = Range("A2", col)

    For Each cell In rngA
        If cell.Value = "Energizer" Then
            If r = 0 Then
                Set copiedRange = cell.EntireRow
                r = 1
            Else
                Set copiedRange = Union(copiedRange, cell.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell


    If r = 1 Then
        copiedRange.Copy
    End If


End Sub
```

As mentioned in the code, if you want to copy the rows directly to a new sheet, add the destination after the copy command.

Comment: Object variable or with block not set. While try to debug it stops near copy comand.

Comment: I changed the code such that the range is only copied if copiedRange is not empty. Does it work now? If not, can you upload your table? Because the code works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If this is really all of your code, you forgot to paste your copied row to the new sheet.